# Any way to implement user access control over directories in Git repositories (give users access only to certain directories in a Git repo)?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Is there any way to implement directory level access control in a Git repository?
This is similar to authz access control in SVN. As Git saves versions by snapshots of the entire repository, I think it is not possible to do so. Then I looked at some of the commercial versions layered or based on Git but could not find any such feature either.

Consider a "project" which has several "submodules" subcontracted to different companies. The company owning the project has a group of developers who develop the module (or the API) that ties these modules together. Since all the files reside in one project (a project is a single repository), there is a need, for proprietary reasons, to prevent access to a subcontractor to source code developed by other subcontractors. One way is to split submodules into different repositories and have them managed separately. That would be inefficient. This is precisely the use case

My questions are:

1. Are commercial implementations available to provide the above features for Git?
2. How to manage software projects using Git where developers are provided access to only those directories in the repository that they need to edit or know about?
3. Is it practical to think of changing Git source code to implement this when the entire design principle of Git for versioning is based upon snapshots of the entire Git repository?
4. Is Git simply not designed for such requirements and that SVN has a clear edge over Git for such requirements?

Comment: do you have a more concrete description of your needs ? like: what kind of content do you want to share ? is it code, or some other form of project ? how much splitting and joining do you have in mind ?

Comment: I will underline that access management is provided by tools *around* git (like github, gitlab, azure, gitolite, ...). The fact that these do not provide a content based access may be partly guided by how "a project" is implemented in git, but it also indicates that users seem to manage. If you want to split a project into several subprojects, you are probably looking for submodules.

Comment: @LeGEC Consider a "project" which has several "submodules" subcontracted to  different companies. The company owning the project has a group of developers who develop the module (or the API) that ties these modules together.  Since all the files reside in one project (a project is a single repository), there is a need, for proprietary reasons, to prevent access to a subcontractor to source code developed by other subcontractors. One way is to split submodules into different repositories and have them managed separately. That would be inefficient. This is precisely the use case.

Comment: ok, I think this description should go in the body of your question. Also : have you already tried to manage said submodules ? do you have elements qualifying your "that would be inefficient" statement ?

Comment: as far as *technical ways* to manage several repositories, you can also look into `git subtree`, or some scripting using `git filter-repo` to export and re-import a subdirectory as a separate repository

Comment: @LeGEC Description augmented in the question. If you are familiar with SVN, then the feature is available in authz configuration file. That is precisely what I am looking for in Git or any commercial offering. I have come to terms that it is not directly supported in Git.

Comment: I'm still unsure where the assumption that "submodules would be inefficient" comes from. If you find any proprietary/commercial git extensions that would solve your problem, their proprietary nature would likely make support in all of the related tooling much harder (I'm thinking of CI/CD for example, but also local developer workflows)). Submodules are not perfect, but they are widely supported.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I used the wrong word "inefficient". Submodules will not prevent access to the code of different modules used. The use case is that the tying/integration API is developed by a dedicated internal group, and only that group has access to all the submodules.

Comment: @Sunny: ok, I learned something about SVN :D regarding your last remark: give access to one dedicated repo for each subcontractor, and create a "one repo to rule them all", to which only the API team has access, with each of the individual repos as submodules,

Comment: @Sunny: how many subteams are we talking about ?

Comment: @Sunny: but submodules could: since each one is a dedicated git repo, you can easily give different access permissions to those submodules. Then you probably also need some way to identify sets of submodules to check out (or maybe just configure everything to tolerate not-checked-out submodules).

Comment: @LeGEC or JoachimSauer Technically you are right and very close to a solution with your suggestion but organizationally it breaks the project structure because you are breaking a natural directory of a project into sub-directories  to be developed and maintained separately. Besides further granularity of access will require more submodules within the modules. **In any case, I will accept this as an answer, if you post it as one, if I do not get a better answer in the next 24 hours or so.**

Comment: @Sunny : it looks like you have a current workflow (which apparently uses SVN ?) If you want more focused ideas, perhaps you could describe your setup in your question ? how many teams ? do you change the scope of accesses on a regular basis ? are the projects very similar (same programming language, defined structure) or very different ? etc ...

Comment: @Sunny: I think any solution will run into the fundamental problem that "all code belongs together" implies that the code is tightly coupled, but "we need to shield people from being able to see part of it" implies loose coupling. You seem to wish for both to be true at the same time and that'll lead to similar technical tension in the actual implementation.

Comment: @LeGEC  You are right - it is a SVN project, maintained inhouse, but with access control even internally. This project needs to be subcontracted out, in pieces. Unfortunately there is a general resistance from subcontractors to use SVN and management needs to maintain the same granular control over access. This is complicated by the legality of agreement of the company with its client for whom the project was developed in the first place. A few inhouse developers have signed NDA and strict non-compete agreements. They form the team that have access to every line of code and do the integration.